# Remove google app (velvet) from android marshmallow

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, bloatware

I want to remove bloatware Velvet apk (Google app) from stock Android Marshmallow on a Nexus 5. I had no problems on Lollipop removing the Google app. It worked perfectly. But on Marshmallow, I get a bootloop if I remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go settings/apps/configure apps (cog)/default apps/assist & voice input select NONE then Reboot, uninstall Google app and reboot and you have no bootloop enjoy!!

Comment: I figured it out a day after I asked this question. :) Thanks a lot buddy. Appreciate your will to help. :)